# how do you make make a sub group by query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry for the vague question. I just didnt know how to explain in a concise way.

I am trying to run a query that groups the `job_modules` per job id. The problem is that there are many `job_dis` in the table and many `job_modules` in a single `job_id`. I just dont know how to do a sub group.

This is what one `job_id` looks like. There are multiple `job_id`’s in the table, but I want the modules grouped.

```
|job_Module_____________|AVG_REC__|JOB_ID__
|DataSelectionProcess   |0.017    |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0.002    |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0        |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0.015    |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0.004    |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0.009    |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0.002    |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0.791    |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0.001    |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0        |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |0.002    |32681
|DataSelectionProcess   |2.14     |32681
|OutputFileProcess      |1.926    |32681
|OutputFileProcess      |0.044    |32681
|OutputFileProcess      |0.001    |32681
|OutputFileProcess      |0.00305  |32681
|OutputFileProcess      |0.00102  |32681
|OutputFileProcess      |0        |32681
|OutputFileProcess      |0.00609  |32681
|RecallMatchCodeProcess |44.16148 |32681
```

Here is the expected result should be all the avg_rec times added together and all of the modules added:

```
|job_Module_____________|AVG_REC__|JOB_ID__
|DataSelectionProcess   |3.017    |32681
|OutputFileProcess      |2.006    |32681
|RecallMatchCodeProcess |44.16148 |32681
```

Here is a query that I am trying to run.

```
Select  job_module, AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS, job_id
        FROM job_step
        where job_id ='32681' or 
                job_id ='32687' or
                job_id ='32714' or
                job_id ='32716' or
                job_id ='32723' or
                job_id ='32743' or
                job_id ='32758' or
                job_id ='32767' or
                job_id ='32768' or
                job_id ='32782' or
                job_id ='32784' or
                job_id ='32800' or
                job_id ='32801' or
                job_id ='32849' or
                job_id ='32851' or
                job_id ='32884' or
                job_id ='32913' or
                job_id ='32928' or
                job_id ='32938' or
                job_id ='32947' or
                job_id ='33089' or
                job_id ='33095'
                group by job_module
                ORDER BY JOB_ID;
```

Comment: Can you add the expected result?

Comment: What kind of grouping are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to group by `job_id` and `job_module` , as in:

```
select job_id, job_module, sum(AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS)
from job_step
where job_id in (
  '32681', '32687', '32714', '32716', '32723',
  '32743', '32758', '32767', '32768', '32782',
  '32784', '32800', '32801', '32849', '32851',
  '32884', '32913', '32928', '32938', '32947',
  '33089', '33095'
)
group by job_id, job_module
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks so much! I edited it to the answer i was looking for but this is correct!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose AVG_REC **time** is in seconds and milliseconds. In this case you need to summarize time correctly - converting milliseconds to seconds by dividing decimal part on 1000 and sum with seconds. It will look like this:

```
SELECT job_id, job_module, 
NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(
SUBSTR(avg_rec_time_millis, 1, instr(avg_rec_time_millis, '.')-1) +
(SUBSTR(avg_rec_time_millis, instr(avg_rec_time_millis, '.')+1)/1000)
)
, 'SECOND') sum_time
FROM job_step
WHERE job_id IN (
'32681', '32687', '32714', '32716', '32723','32743', '32758', '32767', '32768', '32782', '32784',
'32800', '32801', '32849', '32851','32884', '32913', '32928', '32938', '32947', '33089', '33095'
)
GROUP BY job_id, job_module;
```